# Server network connectivity problem

Tags: linux, network-interface

I have a server (RH6 x86_64) that is pingable from a remote host but does not allow ssh. On the server the ssh and network service statuses are both up however the server gets no response when pinging a remote host. If i either restart the networking service or detach/reattach the network cable all issues are resolved; I can ssh from remote host and I get a response when i ping the remote host from server. Everything is fine for maybe a day but then it goes down again with nothing in the dmesg to indicate when or why it went down.

Is there a way that I can possibly see why my network/ssh connection is seemingly silently failing.

Comment: Sounds like either your network interface is losing it's configuration or there is a routing problem. Maybe set up a script that regularly captures the output of `ip addr` and `ip route`, and compare the results when things are working vs. when they are not?

Comment: @larsks Thanks for the info. I will investigate from those angles.